# How do I setup Azure Site To Site VPN on a local windows 10 PC?

Tags: azure, remote-access, azure-vpn

I have followed [this excellent guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcXW-ABTlO4) by BTNHD on youtube on setting up a VPN to a virtual network on Azure. Unfortunately the (local part of the) demo demonstrates connecting from a windows server 2022 VM, and I cannot figure out how this applies to [the windows 10 way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-to-a-vpn-in-windows-3d29aeb1-f497-f6b7-7633-115722c1009c) of connecting to a VPN, and if it is actually possible.

I need to connect locally to azure db's and storage that are setup with private endpoints on an Azure vNet

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Routing and Remote Access Services (RRAS) is a server role. Up to now. it is only available for Windows server systems. So, configuring RRAS on Windows 10 is not supported. And without RRAS, creating a S2S between your local machine to Azure is not possible (unless you have a VPN device). So either you install a Windows server on your machine or use a VPN device for the S2S VPN setup. If the end goal is to connect to Azure and neither of the above is possible, you can also go with P2S VPN. –

Comment: @Imran  Thx! If you  copy paste to an answer, I'll mark it ;)..  Maybe mention Azure P2S in your answer as I discovered this as the solution to my context after posting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/ras/manage-remote-clients/install/step-1-configure-the-remote-access-infrastructure) Remote Access Infrastructure applies to *Windows Server 2022, Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2016*

> Routing and Remote Access Services (RRAS) is a server role primarily designed for Windows Server systems. As of now, RRAS is not supported on Windows 10. This means configuring RRAS directly on a Windows 10 machine is not a viable option.

Creating a Site-to-Site (S2S) VPN between your local machine and Azure is not possible unless you have a VPN device. so, you can install a Windows server on your machine or use a VPN device for the S2S VPN setup to use RRAS and set up a Site-to-Site VPN, you may need to install Windows Server on your local machine. You can obtain an evaluation version from the [Microsoft Evaluation.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-server-2022) & [Hardware requirements for Windows Server installations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/hardware-requirements)

As per your comments you can go with ***Point-to-Site (P2S) VPN*** allows you to connect to Azure resources from a single computer over the internet.

[image]

***Reference***:

[About Azure Point-to-Site VPN connections - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about)